# Ford circles and the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

I graphed the Ford circles for the first few terms in the Fibonacci sequence $\frac{1}{1}, \frac{2}{1}, \frac{3}{2}, \ldots$ as well as a circle with radius $\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$ about the point $(\frac{1}{2}, 0)$.

Interestingly, the large circle overlaps the Ford circles right where they overlap.

[image: lol]

It's one of those things that looks reasonable but I can't really explain. If I didn't know $\phi$ in advance, could I have found that circle?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is going to turn out to be this, if $x > y$ are consecutive Fibonacci numbers, then $$ x^2 - x y - y^2 = \pm 1 $$

Comment: That explains why the smaller circles kiss, but I'm curious about the big one.

For example, without mentioning $\phi$, they all intersect at a constant distance from $(\frac{1}{2}, 0)$. Why is that?

Comment: The successive circles don't intersect at a common distance from $(\frac{1}{2},0)$. Close, but not exact. Let $P_n$ be the point where the $n$-th circle intersects the $(n+1)$-th circle. If you solve algebraically, you'll see that the square of the distance from $P_n$ to the point $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ is exactly $$\frac{F_{2n+3}}{F_{2n+1}}$$

Comment: The square of the distance I get is $\frac{a^2 - ab + 1}{b^2} + \frac{1}{4}$, with $a = F_{2n}$ and $b = F_{2n-1}$. This always simplifies to $\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$. What have we done differently?

Comment: Should add that my $(x, y)$ coordinates are $(\frac{a}{b}, \frac{1}{b})$.

Comment: @lap: For the $n$-th circle, your posted question uses $a=F_{n+1}$ and $b=F_n$. If instead, you use $a=F_{2n}$ and $b=F_{2n-1}$, then your algebraic simplification shows that the distances are, in fact, constant, so for that case, you've answered your own question.